# How to log incoming icmp traffic?

Tags: iptables, ipv6, tcpdump, icmp

I am watching my ip6table and observing an icmp packet arriving and getting dropped at the rate of 1 per second. I am trying to find out what that message is about. I tried using tcpdump (it is definitely not an echo since I explicitly allowed that):

```
tcpdump 'icmp[icmptype] != icmp-echo'

0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

As can be seen, I am seeing nothing. I have also tried logging it with iptables without any success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter 'ip6 and icmp6' is all that works for me.

According to the manpage, tcpdump doesn't support upper-layer filters on icmpv6; at least with my version.

tcpdump version 4.5.1
libpcap version 1.5.3

Comment: Wonderful. I didn't know how to filter. Thanks for teaching me :)